# I trying to partition my disk and i always get less space then i partitioned

Tags: linux, dd, fdisk

So i have

```
[root@archlinux ~]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sde: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Device        Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sde1      2048    534527    532480  260M EFI System
/dev/sde2    534528  63449087  62914560   30G Linux filesystem
/dev/sde3  63449088 273164287 209715200  100G Linux filesystem
```

I want to partition a new Linux filesystem partition of 30G i do

```
n

+30G

w
```

I get

```
[root@archlinux ~]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sde: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sde1       2048    534527    532480  260M EFI System
/dev/sde2     534528  63449087  62914560   30G Linux filesystem
/dev/sde3   63449088 273164287 209715200  100G Linux filesystem
/dev/sde4  273164288 336078847  62914560   30G Linux filesystem
```

But when i trying to test the space on that partition for example:

```
[root@archlinux ~]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde4 bs=512M count=10
dd: error writing '/dev/sde4': No space left on device
4+0 records in
3+0 records out
2005614592 bytes (2.0 GB, 1.9 GiB) copied, 1.24411 s, 1.6 GB/s
```

upd

Output

```
[root@archlinux f3]# ls -la /dev/sdd* 
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 48 Apr 11 16:01 /dev/sdd 
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 49 Apr 11 16:01 /dev/sdd1 
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 50 Apr 11 16:01 /dev/sdd2 
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 51 Apr 11 16:01 /dev/sdd3 
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 52 Apr 11 16:31 /dev/sdd4
```

i get this error, what could it be? I'm doing it over ssh.

Comment: The Superuser question was deemed off-topic and closed. Now, 1.6GB/sec is the fastest disk I have ever seen, and I wonder if /dev/sde4 is a device file. If, as I suspect, it is not, the question is why no device file was created.

Comment: It seems you do not have a device /dev/sde4 and dd command just create file in /dev/ . Use ls -la /dev/sde* to check if device files were created. if some regular files are there - you have to delete them and run partprobe.